# DynamoDB Stream- AWS Lambda Java API - output format not JSON

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am trying to use the aws Java API to create a lambda function that gets triggered on updates to a table in Dynamo DB. I was referring to tutorials in Amazon website (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-dynamodb-create-package.html). The code gets executed without issues but when i see the logs in cloudwatch,i see that the output(record.getDynamodb()) is not in JSON format. Whereas if i use node.js to create the lambda function, the output is in JSON format. Jusy trying to understand what needs to be done to get the output in JSON format. Plese help

```js
public String handleRequest(DynamodbEvent ddbEvent, Context context) {
  for (DynamodbStreamRecord record: ddbEvent.getRecords()) {
    System.out.println(record.getDynamodb());
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the code please!

Comment: DynamodbStreamRecord is a java class, this is deserialized form of the JSON. You can always use an json libraries to convert it JSON, like ObjectMapper from Jackson, but it beats the purpose. Why would u want the JSON format

Comment: public String handleRequest(DynamodbEvent ddbEvent, Context context) {          

         for (DynamodbStreamRecord record : ddbEvent.getRecords())
  {
         System.out.println(record.getDynamodb());
         }
     }

Comment: Hi Shibashis, Thanks for responding. I am trying to use the lambda function as a trigger to track changes to certain fields in Dynamo DB table. I have a scenario where i need to parse the old value and new value, find differences and do some processing. Please let me know if I am not clear. Thanks

Comment: Attaching the java method from amazon tutorials. Apologies for not formatting. Kindly let me know if you need anything else

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655755/how-to-get-the-pure-json-string-from-dynamodb-stream-new-image/44308410#44308410