# From DynamodbStreamRecord map to JSON string

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Let's say I have this situation in which I got a `DynamodbStreamRecord` inside an AWS Lambda.
From this stream record (variable named `record`), I have a chain of Java methods that extracts a map in this way:

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> w1Data = record.getDynamodb().
    getNewImage().  // obtain the image
    get("DT").      // get from key "DT"
    getM().         // obtain the related map
    get("w1_data"). // get from key "w1_data"
    getM();         // obtain the related map
```

Now, I need to transform such `w1Data` map in a JSON string and I tried to use the `org.json.JSONObject` constructor that takes a map as input parameter, followed by a `toString()`:

```
String jsonRepr = new JSONObject(w1Data).toString();
```

But I obtained this strange string:

```
'{"SessionExtraInfo":"{M: {Info={M: {CampaignID={N: 3,}, OriginID={N: 1,}, EntitySourceClassID={N: 8,}},}},}"}'
```

which instead should be something like this:

```
'{"SessionExtraInfo": {"Info": {"OriginID": "1", "CampaignID": "3", "EntitySourceClassID": "8"}}}'
```

Do you have any suggestion to create a valid JSON string from this map without showing the data types specified by DynamoDB?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB Stream has its own JSNON format in which it has an extra key with every value which describes its TYPE i.e S for String, N for Number and BOOL for Boolean value.

You should look into this link http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/Tx1OVH5LUZAFC6T/Announcing-the-Amazon-DynamoDB-Document-Client-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-JavaScript

This has solved another [SO problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712675/formatting-dynamodb-data-to-normal-json-in-aws-lambda) that resembles yours.

Comment: Thank you @Samhash. Yes, I already know about the dedicated JSON representation for DynamoDB and indeed, as I wrote, I'm looking for a possible solution without showing the data types specified by DynamoDB. Anyway, I'm using Java, not Javascript, so the DocumentClient from Javascript AWS SDK is not useful. A possible solution could be to implement a custom method to perform the "translation" but maybe there is a "magic method" from Java SDK I can use but I can't figure out which one.

Comment: @Marco  Did you figure out any solution for this problem?

Comment: duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655755/how-to-get-the-pure-json-string-from-dynamodb-stream-new-image