# Convert DynamoDB special JSON text to normal JSON

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have a file containing data exported from DynamoDB, it has DynamoDB's "special JSON" format:

`{"key1": {"m":{"key2":{"s":"val2"},"key3":{"s":"val3"}}}}`

I need to parse this file and convert the data to DynamoDB item (com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item) or normal JSON (I know how to convert normal JSON to Item)

I found there are ways to convert Map to Item like the following posts:
1. [Converting DynamoDB JSON to Standard JSON with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812278/converting-dynamodb-json-to-standard-json-with-java)
2. [How to get the pure Json string from DynamoDB stream new image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655755/how-to-get-the-pure-json-string-from-dynamodb-stream-new-image)

To use the solutions mentioned in these posts, I need to write code to convert the special JSON to Map.

Is there a native way to convert DynamoDB "special JSON" **text** to normal JSON or directly to DynamoDB item?

Comment: Map refers to Map<String, AttributeValue>. AttributeValue is com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;

Comment: Aside: if you can export in Ion format, the parsing can be easier - [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataExport.Output.html)

Answer (score 2):

please use this function `AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall`

Related docs: [unmarshall-property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html#unmarshall-property)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any either so I wrote some kotlin code to do it

```
// convert dynamodb json map to normal json map
@Suppress("unchecked_cast")
internal fun Map<String, Any>.toSimpleMapValue(): Map<String, Any> {
    return this.mapValues { (_, v) ->
        (v as Map<String, Any>).toSimpleValue()
    }
}

@Suppress("unchecked_cast", "implicit_cast_to_any")
private fun Map<String, Any>.toSimpleValue() : Any {
    require(this.size == 1)

    val list = this.map { (k, v) ->
         when (k) {
            "BOOL" -> when (v) {
                0 -> false
                1 -> true
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value $v for boolean")
            }
            "S" -> v as String
            "N" -> BigDecimal(v as String)
            "B" -> copyAllBytesFrom(v as ByteBuffer)
            "SS" -> LinkedHashSet(v as List<String>)
            "NS" -> LinkedHashSet((v as List<String>).map { BigDecimal(it) })
            "BS" -> LinkedHashSet((v as List<ByteBuffer>).map { copyAllBytesFrom(it) })
            "L" -> ArrayList((v as List<Any>).map { (it as Map<String, Any>).toSimpleValue() })
            "M" -> (v as Map<String, Any>).toSimpleMapValue()

            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key $k")
        }
    }

    return list[0]
}
```

Above should do the same ting as AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall in Javascript SDK.

Then use `Item.fromMap(newImage.toSimpleMapValue())` to convert the DynamoDB Map/Json to Item.

I didn't test all the cases, especially not sure binary type.