# Converting DynamoDB json sqs message to normal json java

Tags: java, json, amazon-dynamodb

We have an upstream client using "Dynamo ->Lambda -> SNS -> SQS" architecture to publish data. We, as a sqs consumer, need to process the message. The SQS message is in the raw dynamo record format like below

```
{"key1": {"m":{"key2":{"s":"val2"},"key3":{"s":"val3"}}}}
```

I want to convert the dynamo json to normal json so that I can use json de-serializer to get a POJO. I saw similar questions on SO but they start either with a [DynamoDbRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333945/converting-dynamodb-json-document-to-json-object-in-java) or Map<String, Attribute> to get normal JSON. I only have the string in SQS message. I found the [Javascript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712675/formatting-dynamodb-data-to-normal-json-in-aws-lambda) but nothing similar in JAVA.

Are there simple built in ways to do this or would I need to parse the string using "S", "N" etc. to get normal json?

Thanks

Comment: which libray are you using for json processing?

Comment: I have tried Jackson ObjectMapper and Gson.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same [DynamoDB document Item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Item.html) in the Java SDK that can take a string:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;

Item item = Item.fromJSON(json);
```

Presumably, it uses Jackson underneath the covers.